# getting trouble when updating specific column values in where I used php implode method is not updating properly

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, explode, implode

I have a table `questions` in where column `answerid` values are like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` . Now I want to update `questions` table when I am going to delete an `answer`  from  `answers` table. Suppose, I am going to delete `5` number answer from `answers` table and also delete this `5` number from `questions` table. But when I am doing this `questions` table is updating like this- `[{"answerid":"1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10"}]` instead I want to update like `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10` . I tried in my method like this-

```
public function deleteAnswer($id)
{
    $questionId = DB::table('answers')->where('id', $id)->get(['questionid']);
    $qid = $questionId[0]->questionid;
    $questionAns = DB::table('questions')->where('id', $qid)->get(['answerid']);

    $ansId = explode(",",$questionAns);
    //dd($ansId);


    while ($aid = current($ansId)) {
        if ($aid == $id) {
            $offset =  key($ansId);
        }
        next($ansId);
    }
   unset($ansId[$offset]);
    $implodeAnsIds = implode(",",$ansId);

   DB::table('questions')->where('id', $qid)->update([
        'answerid' => $implodeAnsIds,
   ]);

   return 'done';

}
```

Comment: Rewrite the title - it is senseless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`get()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_get) method on a query builder will always return a collection. However, you want a single property.

A solution would be to [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_pluck) the `answerid` column and select the first row. This will only select the property you need.

```
$questionAns = DB::table('questions')->where('id', $qid)->pluck('answerid')->first();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I got my expected result.

Comment: @RashedHasan you might want to accept the answer since it solved your problem.